# Change Color of Listbox on Click

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to change the BackColor of my listbox to white. I have succeeded in changing it to red(to show a missing input) but I want it to change back to white when clicked. My code is:

```
Private Sub lstEqualToOrAround_Click()
    lstEqualToOrAround.BackColor = &H8000000F
End Sub
```

By using watch, I can see that the event is triggered and runs the code but it does not change the color. I don't know why.

I have tried making it call another Sub and changing the color from there but I did not work for this case. However, I can do other things within the New Sub or 'Click' event but I cannot change the BackColor

Edit: I have gotten it working using the 'DblClick' event but that is not what I want for the user.(I have to use vba because we have no access to anything else)

Comment: This is possibly a bug. There are workarounds, such as placing a label behind the listbox and changing that colour.

Comment: Is `&H8000000F` supposed to be white? Try `&HFFFFFF` or `vbWhite`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have it so if there is no input in the listbox at the time the Macro needs it, it will change the color to red. When the user clicks the listbox to set input, it should change back to white

Comment: Yes, I understand that. What I'm saying is that the hex value `&H8000000F` does not strike me as "white", since white is RGB(255,255,255), its hex value would be a bunch of `FF`s. If that's the hex code for some data point from the system palette, then it's probably a good idea to declare/name a constant for it instead of hard-coding it, and know that the actual color depends on the user's system settings. If you want the control to be white regardless of system settings, you need an actual "white" hex code, i.e. `&HFFFFFF`, or `vbWhite`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Oh I see. I got that value from the properties of the listbox. You are also absolutely correct in saying that it is not white. I realized that it is gray

Comment: And it could be bright blue on another system ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Because function have not parameter from Screen will cant refesh to screen.

You can use `MouseDown` event instead of `Click` event

```
Private Sub lstEqualToOrAround_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
 lstEqualToOrAround.backColor = &H8000000F
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. So `Me.Refresh` (or is it `.Repaint`? I get them mixed up between MSForms and WinForms) could probably work too in the `Click` handler then?

Comment: So that worked but now the first option on the listbox does not get highllighted when clicked. It still has a value but it won't show the highlight for feedback

Comment: The first choice in the listbox was not returning a value so I had to find a way around. What I did was, put the listbox inside a frame and changed the color of the frame on-click

Comment: @SheldonAranha: i try with first option, it can change color of listbox, i not understand your case can't process.

Comment: @D T, it wasn't letting me choose the top choice in my listbox when I used `MouseDown` so I had to use that workaround. I don't know the reason why it was doing that but I didn't have time to find out