# Cannot change ListBox properties of a VBA form in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, properties, listbox

It is not possible to change the ListBox properties (TextColor, BorderColor, BackColor…) from within the ListBox event procedure. Example:

```
Private Sub MyListBox_Click()
  MyListBox.BackColor = vbGreen
End Sub
```

This has no effect. From within another Subs it works normally.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960181/change-color-of-listbox-on-click

Answer (score 0):

`DblClick()` is the event you are looking for:

```
Private Sub MyListBox_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    MyListBox.BackColor = vbRed
End Sub
```

**But** there are plenty of better ways to do it:

- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154401/handling-dialog-closure-in-a-vba-user-form
- https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-the-perfect-userform-in-vba/ (disclaimer - my article)

Comment: DblClick works well but I cannot use this event since users don't doubleclick the listbox item. The doubleclick actually seletcs and deselects the item again.
ListStyle is fmListStyleOption.

Comment: The first click is not detected. So for the users it will be a single click. Test it.

Comment: Sorry, not getting the point. An item in a listbox gets selected upon a click. Double click on the same item select it and deselect again. Tested.